# How to flip flash.media.Video?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video

I'm playing with the flash.media.Video and the Camera with Actionscript, and it bugs me that the video cam is showing a flipped video. Let me describe with an example:

When I turn to my right, the video will show me turning to my left. If I held up a peace finger sign on my right hand, it appear as if I am doing it with my left.

So, how do I flip the video as to make it look "mirror"?

Answer (score 10):

To make the video look like a "mirror", I pretty much have to set 2 things:

myVideo.scaleX = -1;
myVideo.x = myVideo.width + myVideo.x;

- Thanks Christophe

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by setting the "scaleX" property of you video object to -1.

```
myVideo.scaleX = -1;
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. But this guide did show the solution: http://www.dreaminginflash.com/2008/06/11/as3-flip-vertical-and-flip-horizontal/